# How do I simulate real input into a specific process (Linux/OSX)

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unit-testing

So the title speak by itself but let's be a little more specific.

Let's say I have an "interactive" program who read on STDIN each user input in "non-canonic" mode.
This program take no arguments and you can't give him commands until you are in it.

Take `tig` command as example or a shell like `csh` (well csh can take arguments but let's say he's not for the example).

Let say I want to unit-test the behavior into the program after some specific input.

What is **the most clean way working both on Linux and OSX, and who don't require sudo**, to send data to the program and get the result into my unit-test program ?

So far that what's I've tried:

On **linux**:

```
printf "\E[B" (key arrow down) > /proc/$(pid)/fd/0
```

On **OSX**:

```
printf "\E[B" > /dev/$(tty)
printf "\E[B" > /dev/ustdin
```

But when I execute this kind of commands, I can see the string into the tty of my process. But the process don't act like he received this data on STDIN.

Ex for csh:

```
printf "ls\x10\n" > /proc/$(pid)/fd/0
```

Result:

```
csh: ls
```

Even if I try to make the "return"  by hitting manually enter, csh doesn't receive the `ls` command.

Comment: Have you tried [**expect**](http://expect.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: This same problem is discussed [on serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi). [The top-most answer](http://serverfault.com/a/178470/356862) therein is incorrect but the [last comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi#comment856844_178470) to it gives an insight why this approach doesn't work. See the [second most popular answer](http://serverfault.com/a/547144/356862).

Comment: @Leon yes the screen solution do the tricks Thank's ! I've also found the "(pexepect) [https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/] " module on python who allow more easy handleling.